# Where does initialI18nStore come from with react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-i18next

I wish there was a little more documentation around the useSSR from react-i18next. In the documentation it states to build a component like this...

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSSR } from 'react-i18next';

export function InitSSR({ initialI18nStore, initialLanguage }) {
  useSSR(initialI18nStore, initialLanguage);

  return <App />
}
```

The problem is it doesn't show where the initialI18nStore prop comes from. I get initialLanguage would be something like 'es', 'en', 'etc', but I'm just not sure where initialI18nStore comes from. Is that something from the middleware or the I18nextProvider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

initialI18nStore gets passed down from the server, eg. razzle sample:

server: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/razzle-ssr/src/server.js#L78
client: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/razzle-ssr/src/client.js#L9

for next.js you might have a look at: https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next

And like always...would be happy if you contribute your insights to the documentation - improving it for the next one struggling...